# Unstable insert rate in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, nosql, crud

I have a process that can generate 20 000 records per second (record size ~30Kb). I am trying to insert them as fast as possible into single instance of MongoDB. But I am getting ~1500 inserts per second with unstable rate that ranges from 1000 inserts to 2000 inserts per second. The question is what is the reason and how to fix it? :) Here is data from `mongostat` for 2.5 hours:
[image]

**Set up**

I am running instance in the cloud with 8 cores, 16Gb RAM, 150Gb HDD, Ubuntu 18.04, MongoDB 4.0 [official docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo). On the same instance run 2 workers that generate 10 000 records per second each and `insert_many` them into MongoDB 100 records per chunk. Each record is split between 2 collections `cases` and `docs`, `docs` uses zlib compression. `cases` record is ~1Kb in size on average. Random record as an example:

```
{'info': {'judge': 'Орлова Олеся Викторовна', 'decision': 'Отменено с возвращением на новое рассмотрение', 'entry_date': datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 1, 0, 0), 'number': '12-48/2017 (12-413/2016;)', 'decision_date': datetime.datetime(2017, 2, 9, 0, 0)}, 'acts': [{'doc': ObjectId('5c3c76543d495a000c97243b'), 'type': 'Решение'}], '_id': ObjectId('5c3c76543d495a000c97243a'), 'sides': [{'name': 'Кузнецов П. В.', 'articles': 'КоАП: ст. 5.27.1 ч.4'}], 'history': [{'timestamp': datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 1, 15, 6), 'type': 'Материалы переданы в производство судье'}, {'timestamp': datetime.datetime(2017, 2, 9, 16, 0), 'type': 'Судебное заседание', 'decision': 'Отменено с возвращением на новое рассмотрение'}, {'timestamp': datetime.datetime(2017, 2, 17, 15, 6), 'type': 'Дело сдано в отдел судебного делопроизводства'}, {'timestamp': datetime.datetime(2017, 2, 17, 15, 7), 'type': 'Вручение копии решения (определения) в соотв. с чч. 2, 2.1, 2.2 ст. 30.8 КоАП РФ'}, {'timestamp': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 13, 16, 6), 'type': 'Вступило в законную силу'}, {'timestamp': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 14, 16, 6), 'type': 'Дело оформлено'}, {'timestamp': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 29, 14, 33), 'type': 'Дело передано в архив'}], 'source': {'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 1, 0, 0), 'engine': 'v1', 'instance': 'appeal', 'host': 'bratsky.irk.sudrf.ru', 'process': 'adm_nar', 'crawled': datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 22, 8, 15, 7), 'url': 'https://bratsky--irk.sudrf.ru/modules.php?name=sud_delo&srv_num=1&name_op=case&case_id=53033119&case_uid=A84C1A34-846D-4912-8242-C7657985873B&delo_id=1502001'}, 'id': '53033119_A84C1A34-846D-4912-8242-C7657985873B_1_'}
```

`docs` record is ~30Kb on average:

```
{'_id': ObjectId('5c3c76543d495a000c97243b'), 'data': '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.....TlQ6IDAuNWluOyBURVhULUFMSUdOOiBqdXN0aWZ5Ij7QoNC10YjQtdC90LjQtSDQvNC+0LbQtdGCINCx0YvRgtGMINC+0LHQttCw0LvQvtCy0LDQvdC+INCyINCY0YDQutGD0YLRgdC60LjQuSDQvtCx0LvQsNGB0YLQvdC+0Lkg0YHRg9C0INCyINGC0LXRh9C10L3QuNC1IDEwINGB0YPRgtC+0Log0YEg0LzQvtC80LXQvdGC0LAg0L/QvtC70YPRh9C10L3QuNGPINC10LPQviDQutC+0L/QuNC4LjwvUD4NCjxQIHN0eWxlPSJURVhULUlOREVOVDogMC41aW47IFRFWFQtQUxJR046IGp1c3RpZnkiPtCh0YPQtNGM0Y8g0J4u0JIuINCe0YDQu9C+0LLQsDwvUD48L1NQQU4+PC9CT0RZPjwvSFRNTD4=', 'extension': '.html'}
```

**Analysis**

To figure out what is going on I use `docker stats` and `mongostat`. Key metrics are highlighted:
[image]
[image]

I collect metrics for 2.5 hours during data insertion and plot `CPU %`, `insert`, `dirty` from pictures above:
[image]

One can see that insert rate drops when dirty peaks at 20% and goes up to ~2000 when dirty is lower then 20%:
[image]

Dirty goes down when CPU is active. One can see that when `cpu` is ~300% `dirty` starts to go down (plots are a bit out of sick since `docker stats` and `mongostat` run separately), when `cpu` is 200% `dirty` grows back to 20% and inserts slow down:
[image]

**Question**

1. Is my analysis correct? It is my first time using MongoDB so I may be wrong
2. If analysis is correct why MongoDB does not always use 300%+ CPU (instance has 8 cores) to keep `dirty` low and insert rate high? Is it possible to force it to do so and is it the right way solve my issue?

**Update**

Maybe HDD IO is an issue?

I did not log IO utilisation, but

1. I remember looking into cloud.mongodb.com/freemonitoring during insertion process, there is a plot called "Disk Utilisation", it was 50% max
2. Currently my problem is insert rate *instability*. I am ok with current 2000 inserts per seconds max. It means that current HDD can handle that, right? I do not understand why periodically insert rate drops to 1000.

On sharding

Currently I am trying to reach max performance on single machine

**Solution**

Just change HDD to SSD.

Before:
[image: before]

After:
[image: after]

With the same ~1500 inserts per second, dirty is stable at ~5%. Inserts and CPU usage is now stable. This is the behaviour I expected to see. SSD solves the problem from the title of this question "Unstable insert rate in MongoDB"

Comment: I'd expect disk IO to be the bottleneck here, not CPU.

Comment: Agree with @RobbyCornelissen here. Disk IO plays a big role. Also, We switched to SSD from HDD and noticed 10x change in performance. For insertMany I use from 500 - 1000 at once to insert. When I tested for my server, I saw around 30k inserts in 5-6seconds. You should also consider Clustering and Sharding if you are going to see 10k rec per second.

Comment: Thank you for your response, added "Update" section in response to your questions. Basically question is about *instability*. I see that system can do 2000 inserts per seconds. Currently I am ok with that. It means that current HDD can handle that, right? The question is why periodically insert rate drops to 1000

Comment: Mongodb or any other server will have their housekeeping tasks as well. CPU and Disk get busy with those tasks as well. If you want to do know more on what's happening, mongodb logs are a way to go. You can also set verbosity levels. Use db.setLogLevel() as per your choice as mentioned in https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/log-messages/

Comment: I would try using snappy rather than zlib for compression - it's less likely to cause problems and variance. And I agree with @simagix to check your iowait.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a better disk will definitely improve the performance.  There are other metrics you can monitor.

- The percentage of dirty bytes indicates data is modified in wiredTiger cache but not persisted to the disk yet. You should monitor your disk IOPS if it has reach your provisioned limit.  Use command `iostat` to monitor or get it from MongoDB FTDC data.
- When your CPU spikes, monitor whether if CPU time spent on *iowait*.  If the *iowait %* is high, you have I/O blocking, i.e. faster disk or more IOPS will help.
- Monitor the *qrw* (queued read and write requests) and *arw* (active read and write requests) from `mongostat` output.  If these numbers remain low like your sample output, especially the *qrw*, mongo is able to support your requests without queuing requests up.
- Avoid resources competition by moving the injection works to other instances.
- You can further optimize using different disk partitions for mongo data path and journal location.
- Clients (ingestion workers) performance is usually ignored by observers.  The CPU spike might be from your workers and thus had lower throughputs.  Monitor clients performance using `top` command or equivalent.

Hope the above help.

Comment: Thanks you very much, changing HDD to SSD solved my issue. Updated the question, described my observations in "Solution" section